# Regex issue parsing data

Tags: regex

I currently have the following regex :

```
(\d{7})\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s([a-zA-Z\-\s\&\#\,\'\.\/\(\)\d]*)\s(\d+[\w\.\/\#]*)\s([a-zA-Z\/\&\s\d\*\-]*\d{0,1}\.{0,1}\d*[a-zA-Z]*)\s([a-zA-Z]*[\d+\.{0,1}\-{0,1}\d]+[a-zA-Z]*)\s(\d+)\s([a-zA-Z]*[\d+\.{0,1}\-{0,1}\d]+[a-zA-Z\s]*)\s([\(\d\,]*\.\d+[\)]*)\s([\(\d\,]*\.\d+[\)]*)\s([\(]*\${1}[\d\.\,\)]*)\s([a-zA-Z\s\$\.\d\/]*)\s([\(]*\${1}[\d\,]+\.\d{0,2}[\)]*)(\d+)
```

The input string being parsed is :

```
6655738 03/31/2017 OTTER CREEK COUNTRY STORES, INC RICHS 72/ 2.5 OZ DONUT JUMBO RING 03853 989200 00049800038530 1.00 12.90 $21.21 $2.00 Per Unit $2.00109830
```

The 3rd group is returning `OTTER CREEK COUNTRY STORES, INC RICHS 72/` whereas I want only `OTTER CREEK COUNTRY STORES, INC RICHS`.

Could someone tell me what to change in the regex to make this work?

Comment: What language do you use ? (don't ask a regex question without specifying the language, the tool or the regex engine you use with the appropriate tag).

Comment: I am using this in a tool which uses java.util.regex

Answer (score 0):

Your third group is: `([a-zA-Z\-\s\&\#\,\'\.\/\(\)\d]*)` which includes numbers and slashes. If you don't want these, put them outside the group.

But the correct solution depends on the format of your input string. Maybe the third group has a length dependency - then your regexp needs to have a different setup.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There is no dependency on the length. The 3rd group should be what I mentioned already. 4th group should be 72/ 2.5 OZ. Not sure how to get it.